# What is wrong with my power supply design in LTspice

Tags: power-supply, ltspice, simulation

What is wrong with my power supply design in LTspice?

I have re-created a Lab Power Supply design from the EEVBlog YouTube channel (see image 1) in LTSpice (see image 2).
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]
However, when I run the simulation in LTSpice, the simulation does not seem to converge and runs indefinitely.

Any advice that anyone an provide in relation to what I may have done wrong with capturing the circuit schematic correctly in LTSpice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You opened two questions about this?

Comment: It's related to simulating the same schematic in different simulators, and I am experiencing different issues from both. Thought about combining the questions. But, was wary of being told that I should've separated them.

Comment: Lt1009 is hooked up wrong. You tied stuff to the trim pin that should be on the cathode.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I am not familiar with Lt1009 or how it is meant to be used. So, my follow on question is, "is the trim pin of the Lt1009 meant to be unconnected in  LTSpice, given that it is not shown on the initial schematic"? Also, I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to have had any impact on the simulation time.